# Missing Item from MODX MIGX

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have a list of images and respective text data that I display using MIGX/getImageList.

This works fine until my list contains a 13th item. At that point, it will select one list item, and not display it. The item not displayed is not the last item in the list, and all 13 show up on the back end.

The item that does not display can be altered by changing the order of the list, but the index of the item missing is not always the same. The same item remains missing until a re-order and save is done - i.e. it's not randomly hiding a different item every time I reload.

I see no reference to any limit in the templates. Nor do I see a reference to 12, or 13. The text data and image in the items are clean, and have been working for the 12 items for almost 8 months.

Here's some code:

tpl

```
   <div class="management_box">
  <div class="management_img">
    <img  src="[[+image:phpthumbof=`w=100&z=1`]]" alt="[[+pagetitle]]" />
  </div>
    <div class="management_content">
      <h2>[[+name]]</h2>
      <h3>[[+position]]</h3>
      [[+descr]]
      <a href="#[[+name:stripString=` `]]" class="show_more">Show more</a>
    </div>
    <div id="[[+name:stripString=` `]]" class="fulldescr">
    <img  src="[[+image:phpthumbof=`w=100&z=1`]]" alt="[[+pagetitle]]" />
    <h2>[[+name]]</h2>
    <h3>[[+position]]</h3>
    [[+fulldescr]]
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Template

```
<div id="content">   
        [[!getImageList? 
        &tvname=`management` 
        &docid=`[[*id]]` 
        &tpl=`management_tpl` 
        &limit=`0`
    ]]
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
```

I was handed this site to maintain, so I did not build it. Pardon me if I'm not entirely familiar with ModX!

-Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this post in the future - my MIGX plugin was outdated and had some flaws. an update to the plugin fixed everything.